# Eclipse - Making a file quickly accessbile

Tags: eclipse, spring

I use eclipse (Spring STS actually). I need quick access to two files:
- web.xml
- servlet-context.xml (spring config)

Every time I want to open the files, I need to find them and that takes time.

Is there a way to create a link on the root folder of a project? This way I can quickly access it?

Thanks!

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + R` will show a dialog to let you open either file quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `Ctrl+Shift+R` and type the name of the file that you want to open.

You can also create a link to some file under the root of the project:

1. Right click the project and select `New->File`
2. In the New File dialog click `Advanced` and then select `Link to file in the file system`
3. Click `Browse` and select the file for which you want to have quick access
4. Click `Finish` and you are done

Comment: Thanks! The second option is what I was looking for!